# Can't fetch products from apple

Tags: swift, xcode, storekit

I'm using the apphud IOS SDK to fetch products from apple and I get the following error:

```
[StoreKit] Did not receive any products or error for products request.
```

Here's my code:

```
public func loadProducts() async {
   do {
       if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
          let products = try await Apphud.fetchProducts()
          print("products successfully fetched: \(products.map { $0.id })")
       }
   } catch {
            print("products fetch error = \(error)")
   }
}
```

I searched online and saw that some people are running into the same issue. Does anyone know a solution?